# Lambda expression coding variation for optional.filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I am trying to experiment with lambda expressions, is there any other way we can write filter ( `optional.filter(s -> (s.length() > 4))` )

This is complete working code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Optional<String> optional = Optional.of("Hello");

        System.out.println(optional.filter(s -> (s.length() > 4)).get());
    }
}
```

For example one wrong way is below, though it throws compilation saying "can not resolve method length" but here with this trying to explain kind of variation I am thinking.

```
optional.filter(length() > 4)
```

Comment: You had it correct. You need `s -> s.length()` section.

Comment: @menteith it gives compilation error, " bad return type ... "

Comment: It won't give any compilation error on my side.

Comment: No, you can't use any arbitrarily made-up syntax. Only theone supported and defined in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @menteith I am already using this variation in working code given in question, yes works well and one way to write.

Comment: There is no question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to introduce syntax that is not allowed in java.

These are the valid syntax:

```
optional.filter(s -> s.length() > 4)
```

or:

```
optional.filter(s -> {
     return s.length() > 4;
})
```

or:

```
optional.filter(new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            return s.length() > 4
        }
})
```

You should prefer the first in this specific case as it's more compact and readable.

Comment: @Eugene to some extent yes I guess. I wonder how Java would look if every proposed feature was to be implemented into the language (_if possible_) ;). probably not so good.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write complex operations in the stream chain, you can always define the `Function` / `Predicate` / etc separately and just use them. It also increases readability.

For example, you can define a `Predicate` for you case like below:

```
Predicate<String> byStrLengthCheck = s -> s.length() > 4;
```

And use the above `Predicate` like below:

```
System.out.println(optional.filter(byStrLengthCheck).get());
```